# The bug "probably" gets stuck!

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

**Consider a regular tetrahedron with vertices $A,B,C,D$. A bug starts crawling from $A$. The bug moves from one vertex to the other along the edges continuously until it reaches $D$, where there is glue and hence once the bug reaches $D$, it gets stuck. The bug can move to any one vertex from any other vertex with equal probability. Then, find the probability that the bug reaches $D$ from $B$.**

There seems to be varying answers to this question from different people (with $1/4$ and $1/5$ being the commonest responses). What can be the possible equation to be framed? Any hint is appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $p_A$ be the probability that the bug reaches $D$ from $B$ given that it is currently at $A$.

Let $p_B$ be the probability that the bug reaches $D$ from $B$ given that it is currently at $B$.

Let $p_C$ be the probability that the bug reaches $D$ from $B$ given that it is currently at $C$.

We want the value of $p_A$.

If the bug is currently at $A$, then the bug has:

a $\frac{1}{3}$ chance of going to $B$, from which there is a $p_B$ probability of reaching $D$ from $B$,

a $\frac{1}{3}$ chance of going to $C$, from which there is a $p_C$ probability of reaching $D$ from $B$,

a $\frac{1}{3}$ chance of going to $D$, from which there is a no chance of reaching $D$ from $B$.

Therefore, $p_A = \frac{1}{3} \cdot p_B+\frac{1}{3} \cdot p_C+\frac{1}{3} \cdot 0$.

By similar logic, you can get equations for $p_B$ and $p_C$.

This gives you a system of 3 linear equations for 3 variables. Solve this to get $p_A$.

Comment: Do you think the question demands $B$ to be just a "transition" point and not the second last point? That is, $ABAD$ is allowed or only the sequences ending in $BD$ are allowed?

Comment: I interpreted the question as asking the probability that the bug's path ends in $BD$. So, $ABAD$ wouldn't count as reaching $D$ from $B$. Otherwise, they could have phrased the question as "Find the probability that the bug reaches $B$ before reaching $D$".

Answer (score 2):

The bug will get stuck at $D$ with probability $1$.  Note that this does not say that there are no series that avoid $D$-you could alternate $A$ and $B$ forever, but the chance is zero.  The question really asks, given that the bug travels from $A$ to $D$, what is the chance it visits $B$ on the way. As the chance the first move is to $B$ is $1/3$, it is obvious that $1/4$ and $1/5$ are wrong.

This is a Markov chain, but you need to distinguish all the states.  Starting you are at $A$ and have not visited $B$ or $C$.  You have two states being at $A$ depending on whether you have visited $B$ or not (for this problem it doesn't matter if you have visited $C$), two states at $C$, and one state at $B,D$, with $D$ absorbing.  Write your transition matrix and use your usual techniques.

Comment: Thanks indeed but Markov Chains are not included in our probability course right now. So I do not know it, sorry. Do you think this can be solved without using the Markov Chain?

Comment: My understanding is that the problem is asking the probability of the event that the last visit of the bug before it get stuck is $B$. In this case, using the Markov chain technique, the probability is $1/4$.

Comment: ^I also interpreted the problem in the same way and got $1/4$ as the answer. If the bug started at $B$, then the probability would have been $1/2$.

Comment: Like, supposing $p$ to be the probability that the bug reaches $D$, the equation is: $p=(1/3)+p(1/3)+p(1/3)$ giving $p=1$. Reason is: $p$ is the probability of reaching not only $D$ but any arbitrary vertex due to the symmetry of the problem. So prob of reaching D= prob of reaching B = prob of reaching C. Do you think this is right? I would like a similar "equation" given I do not possess knowledge about Markov Chains.

Comment: Please note that in the above comment, $p$ represents the probability that the bug gets stuck, starting its journey from A

Answer (score 2):

Using symmetry, you can cut down the number of variables a bit more and extend this to the case of a complete graph with $n$ vertices - the tetrahedron is the case with $n=4$. Assume that the bug starts from vertex $curr$ and that the designated end vertex is $glue(\neq curr)$. Let $p_{v}$ and $p_{other}$ be the probabilities of bug reaching $glue$ from the vertex $v$ and from set of vertices not equal $curr$, respectively. (Note that, as in the question, "from" refers to the last vertex the bug visits before reaching $glue$.)

Since the bug moves from one vertex to another uniformly at random, the probability that it will reach $glue$ is $1$. Therefore,  $\begin{equation} p_{curr} + p_{other} = 1\end{equation}$. Also, $\forall v \notin \{curr, glue\}, p_{v} = \frac{p_{other}}{n-2}$. Lastly, $p_{curr} = \frac{1}{n-1} + \frac{n-2}{n-1}*\frac{p_{other}}{n-2}$. Reducing these equations, we get $p_{curr} = \frac{2}{n}, p_{other} = \frac{n-2}{n}, p_{v} \forall v \notin \{curr, glue\} = \frac{1}{n}$.